# Connecting to Remote Spark Cluster for TitanDB SparkGraphComputer

Tags: apache-spark, titan, gremlin

I am attempting to leverage a Hadoop Spark Cluster in order to batch load a graph into Titan using the SparkGraphComputer and BulkLoaderVertex program, as specified [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.0-incubating/#sparkgraphcomputer). This requires setting the spark configuration in a properties file, telling Titan where Spark is located, where to read the graph input from, where to store its output, etc.

The problem is that all of the examples seem to specify a local spark cluster through the option:

```
spark.master=local[*]
```

I, however, want to run this job on a remote Spark cluster which is on the same VNet as the VM where the titan instance is hosted. From what I have read, it seems that this can be accomplished by setting

```
spark.master=<spark_master_IP>:7077
```

This is giving me the error that all Spark masters are unresponsive, which disallows me from sending the job to the spark cluster to distribute the batch loading computations.

For reference, I am using Titan 1.0.0 and a Spark 1.6.4 cluster, which are both hosted on the same VNet. Spark is being managed by yarn, which also may be contributing to this difficulty.

Any sort of help/reference would be appreciated. I am sure that I have the correct IP for the spark master, and that I am using the right gremlin commands to accomplish bulk loading through the SparkGraphComputer. What I am not sure about is how to properly configure the Hadoop properties file in order to get Titan to communicate with a remote Spark cluster over a VNet.

Comment: On the Titan instance, are you able to connect to `spark_master:7077`?

Comment: I can connect in that I can ping the IP and get a response, and issue curl/wget requests to that port without the connection getting refused. But those requests don't give me any data back, and using that IP in my titan config gives me the error that all masters are unresponsive.

Comment: Does your master string look like this? `spark://ip:7077`

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly how I have it. It seems like it can connect, but isn't getting a response from Spark (since the error message is that all spark masters are unresponsive)

Comment: Have you tried running another simple or test application to see if the cluster runs properly?

Comment: Yeah the cluster is running properly -- it has its own copy of the graph, and can receive/process different jobs on it. The goal now is to use the BulkLoaderVertexProgram to load the graph from spark into titan in batch, using the remote SparkGraphComputer to do the loading.

Comment: FWIW, Titan 1.0 is built with [TinkerPop 3.0.1](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/1.0.0/pom.xml#L62), and TinkerPop 3.0.1 uses [Spark 1.2.1](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/3.0.1-incubating/hadoop-gremlin/pom.xml#L115). You could be running into version mismatch issues.